# How to get ( child ) fields created by acf-address-field plugin of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Advanced Custom Field Plugin along with [acf-address-field](https://github.com/GCX/acf-address-field). It creates a field 'address' which has child fields ( address1, address2, address3, city etc. ). When I try to get field using following code it works:

```
get_field('address');
```

It shows every thing but in html tags. For some reason I need just few child fields for example address1. I try to get it using following code but no luck:

```
get_field('address1');
```

It just show "false". Can any one please tell me how to get address1 field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code for the acf-address-field plugin and saw this function:

```
public function get_value( $post_id, $field ){...}
```

try calling that instead of get_field()